# Extending URL rewrite rule to include more arguments

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using the following mod_rewrite in `.htaccess`
which processes `HOSTNAME/controller/action/id`

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]*)/?([a-zA-Z]*)?/?([a-zA-Z0-9]*)?/?$ index.php?controller=$1&action=$2&id=$3 [NC,L]
```

I want to change this so that the url can contain more arguments like this:

`HOSTNAME/controller/action/arg1/arg2/arg3`

`index.php?controller=$1&action=$2&arg1=$3&arg2=$4&arg3=$5`.

I know this involves changing the regex before it but, I do not understand regex, and have attempted to do it on [mod rewrite generator](http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/index.php) which  thought looked simple but I still can't get it to work.

**Edit** In addition, could somebody break down the parts of this particular regex, so help give me a beginners understanding of what does what.

**Edit2**

After just studying the regex pattern and doing some searches, I am thinking the following:

`^` - start of string

`([a-zA-Z]*)` - a-Z strings before the first

`/` delimeter

`?([a-zA-Z]*)?` - a-Z strings after the first but before the 2nd

`/` delimeter

`?([a-zA-Z0-9]*)?` a-9 strings after the 2nd, but before the 3rd

`/` delimeter

`?$` - put each in a $ variable in sequence?

Anyway I'm going to try adding an extra 2 arguments based on this theory and will post my results.

**Edit3**

After both discovering a solution myself, and implementing the solution provided by [arkascha](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35393730/5579365). I have decided to accept [arkascha's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35393730/5579365) as a much better and flexible way to handle multiple arguments in a url. You do however have to refer to them by index in the `$path` array.

On the contrary, if you know that you are going to only be using a fixed or maximum amount of arguments, you can use my solution. using this you also benefit from being able to refer to the URL elements as `$_GET['controller'], $_GET['action'] $_GET['arg1']` etc.

Comment: Sorry, the question is unclear. Please give a clear example what request URL you want to rewrite to what internal target.

Comment: I would actually only do a basic rewriting to the `index.php` script internally and then do further processing of the arguments inside your php router by examining the `$_REQUEST` information. That is much more flexible and easier to debug.

Comment: Can you provide an example? I don't see how this would work without rewriting the URL to take more arguments like that, otherwise if I include a 2nd argument, I will get a 404 because apache is looking for a path.

Comment: In fact, I'm certain that I need to change the regex here, because anything after `controller/action/id` will be ignored by apache, and thus my php script won't be able to find them in the `$_GET` array.

Comment: Sorry, but that is simply not true, what I suggest certainly _does_ work. I posted an answer below as a primitive example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said above in the comments I suggest to only do some basic rewriting inside the http servers rewrite module. This is a bit like the strategy typically implemented when using the nginx http server. That leaves flexibility to implement additional request handling inside the php engine. Also you do not have to modify your rewriting pattern.

Obviously the exact pattern depends in the request, this is just a basic example:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/css
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [L]
```

Now you can further examine the actual request inside your php script:

```
<?php
$request = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
var_dump([
  'path' => explode('/', $request['path']),
  'args' => explode('&', $request['query']),
]);
```

A request to `https://example.org/controller/action/arg1/arg2?foo=bar will give that output:

```
array (size=3)
  'path' => 
    array (size=5)
      0 => string '' (length=0)
      1 => string 'controller' (length=10)
      2 => string 'action' (length=6)
      3 => string 'arg1' (length=4)
      4 => string 'arg2' (length=4)
  'args' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string 'foo=bar' (length=7)
```

Comment: I certainly do prefer this, and am trying to implement it now, I will post back after modify some of my code. Looks quite exciting though!

Comment: Just to clarify, why does the path array bring back an empty string for 0? does `parse_url` remove the host?

Comment: The host is _not_ part of the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`. The empty entry simply results from the leading slash. You can either simply ignore that static empty entry (recommended) or use this modification: `explode('/', substr($request['path'], 1))`.

Comment: Sorry, I just realize my last comment was nonsense. Obviously what _should_ have been initially said is that the hostname is not part of the `path` component of the result of the `parse_url()` call. Sorry for that!

Comment: No worries, either way I got an understanding of it!

Comment: Okay, so I have implemented it, pretty much perfectly barring a few which ill change over time.  the problem I am facing now though is that I use absolute URL's for my css and images.  and now when my main template wants to get to `host/css/default.css` it thinks that css is a controller!

Comment: No worries, you can simply add exceptions using the `RewriteCond` command. I modified the trivial rewrite example in the answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103431/discussion-between-adam-copley-and-arkascha).

Answer (score 2):

After doing some digging, and assuming that what I mentioned in **Edit2** is true, it was the correct solution. And so I will post as an answer for future readers.

`^` - start of string

`([a-zA-Z]*)` - a-Z strings before the first

`/` delimeter

`?([a-zA-Z]*)?` - a-Z strings after the first but before the 2nd

`/` delimeter

`?([a-zA-Z0-9]*)?` a-9 strings after the 2nd, but before the 3rd

`/` delimeter

`?$` - put each in a $ variable in sequence

and so just extending the url rewrite like this works perfectly:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]*)/?([a-zA-Z]*)?/?([a-zA-Z0-9]*)?/?([a-zA-Z0-9]*)?/?([a-zA-Z0-9]*)?/?$ index.php?controller=$1&action=$2&arg1=$3&arg2=$4&arg3=$5 [NC,L]
```

Comment: URLs certainly can contain more characters than what is detected in this pattern...